# the media query am applying is not working accordingly

Tags: html, css, background, css-selectors, media-queries

I Don't know why the media query am applying is not working for the specific screen size the .container class is working normally but not when the media query

```
container {
background: url(imaggg/astronaut2.png);
background-position: center;
background-size: 90px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 2.3% 12.5%;
width: 29%;
height: 17%;
}



@media (max-width: 800px) {
.container {
    background: none;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 90px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 2.3% 12.5%;
    width: 29%;
    height: 17%;
}
}
```

Comment: Pleade be more specific, the css inside the query dosen't apply when the browser width is less than 800px? In your code you miss  `.` near container is this a typo?

Comment: . near container is not not a typo actually when i was copying the code to paste it here i forgot to add the . but in the real code it is there and the media query is still not working

Comment: Can you give us more details? not working it's a bit generic

Comment: i just restart my browser XD.

Comment: Just cache problem, i'll vote to close this question

Answer (score 0):

You should add `screen and` after `@media`

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    background: none;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 90px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 2.3% 12.5%;
    width: 29%;
    height: 17%;
  }
}
```

Comment: @media (max-width: 800px) { this is also correct

Comment: ```screen and``` is not required.

Comment: yes, `screen` is not required, but I think he should try to add it. it maybe can solve his problem.

Comment: i tried to add screen and it doesn't work

Comment: @anujtanwar I checked and it's still working. https://codepen.io/tuandaodev/pen/ZEyNoqx. Did you miss `.` before first `container`?

Comment: thank u, it worked i had to restart my browser XD